# What is the closest value to 1/3 that can be achieved using IEEE 754 32-bit floating point format?

Tags: floating-point

I'm having trouble completing the problem despite having a fairly good understanding of how the floating point format works. Can someone walk me through the steps one would take to arrive at an answer? Why is it impossible to represent 1/3 entirely, and how do we know we've gotten to a number closest to 1/3?

Answer (score 2):

The fraction part of a *float* in IEEE 754 is made from the sum of negative powers of 2.

For instance, 0.5 is 2<sup>-1</sup>, 0.75 is 2<sup>-1</sup>+2<sup>-2</sup> etc...

To help you in your work, consider

- what number approaches 1/3 by summing [N bits](http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/coding/ieeefloat.html) of negative powers of 2?
- and 1/3 being infinite, you cannot have exactly 1/3 within a finite number of bits (32) float

To complete the question, you can implement a fairly easy algorithm to reach a value close to 1/3

```
N = 23    // mantissa bits
T = 1/3   // target
p = 0.5   // first negative power of 2
r = 0.0   // resultat

do N times 
  if ( r + p <= T ) r = r + p // add power of 2 if result is not bigger than target
  p = p / 2  // next power of 2
done
```

To visualize the result in binary, you could print "1" when *p* is added to *r*, and "0" when it's not.
The last bit could be "1" to round the result closer to the target.

Answer (score 1):

To answer “How close can we get?” questions with floating-point, it is often useful to change the significand (fraction portion) to an integer. To do this, start with the customary floating-point format for normal 32-bit binary IEEE floating-point numbers:

- A sign s (0 or 1 representing + or –), an exponent e, and a fraction f that begins with “1.” and has 23 bits after the decimal point. These three parts combine to represent the number (–1)<sup>s</sup>•2<sup>e</sup>•f.

Then scale the format so the fraction f is instead an integer F. To do this, we subtract 23 from the exponent and multiply the fraction f by 2<sup>23</sup>. Then we have this format:

- A sign s, an exponent e–23, and an integer F equal to 2<sup>23</sup>•f (so 2<sup>23</sup> ≤ F < 2<sup>24</sup>). These parts combine to represent the number  (–1)<sup>s</sup>•2<sup>e–23</sup>•F =  (–1)<sup>s</sup>•2<sup>e</sup>•f.

Now, figure out what exponent 1/3 would have in the customary format. To make f start with “1.”, e must be -2. We can see this from the fact that 1/3 = 2<sup>–2</sup>•4/3, and 1 ≤ 4/3 < 2, so, in binary, 4/3 starts with “1.”.

Then, consider the scaled format. In this format, we must have: The sign s is 0, the exponent is –2–23 = –25, and F is some integer such that (–1)<sup>0</sup>•2<sup>–25</sup>•F ≈ 1/3.

This is easy to solve, F ≈ 2<sup>25</sup>•1/3 = 33554432/3 = 11184810.666…. The nearest integer to this value is 11184811, so F = 11184811.

Now we can see the error in F is 1/3 (the difference between the integer that F must be and the value we would like it to be), and that error is scaled by 2<sup>-25</sup>, so the error is 2<sup>-25</sup>/3 ≈ 9.934e-09. And the value itself is 2<sup>–25</sup>•11184811, which is approximately .3333333433.

(Note that I addressed only normal numbers. For numbers near the limits of the floating-point format, overflow and underflow must also be considered.)

Comment: How can you represent this value as a floating point number in 0's and 1's?  Would it be like converting a decimal value in base 10 to a floating point?

Comment: To show the value as floating-point with binary, you can convert the integer F to binary (11184811 is AAAAAB in hex, so 101010101010101010101011 in binary) and show it with a “.” after the first bit and the exponent from the customary floating-point format, so 1.01010101010101010101011•2**-2. If you want fixed-point instead of floating the point with an exponent, just shift the point by the amount shown in the exponent, producing .0101010101010101010101011.

Comment: On the other hand, if you do not want to show the value in binary but rather want to show its encoding in floating-point, then convert the sign to a bit (0 for +), adjust the exponent by the bias (127 according to the IEEE specification, so -2 becomes 125) and convert it to 7-bit binary (0111101), and remove the first bit of F (leaving  01010101010101010101011). Then put the bits together: 0 0111101 01010101010101010101011.